# How to monetize Mobile app with google ad manager

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application, google-ad-manager, google-mobile-ads

I am developing a mobile application and for monetization I chose google ad manager when I tested the banner and interstitial using test ad unit ID (/ 6499 / example / banner
) it shows the test ads, but when I use my ad unit ID (/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx) it doesn't go up.

Answer (score 0):

Test ads are shown but when you use real adUnitId they needed time to configure. It needs 5-6 requests to start showing ads. Just publish the app with real adunitids and it will show ads. Also the fill rate is less in real ads i.e. you will not get ads for every request.

Comment: Ok For test id unit it (/ 6499 / example / banner ) and for the real it (xxxxx/xxxxx) or (/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/banner)  ?